# Invalid Date format for Simplified Chinese

Tags: android, jodatime

I am getting an `Illegal Argument Exception` from the `Joda` time library but only in simplified *Chinese*.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "10月 01, 2015 10:25 PM"
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(Unknown Source)
```

My knowledge of Chinese is zero so I am not sure why it is failing.

Comment: "PM" is certainly not Chinese but English. I suspect that the parse engine complains about the use of different languages at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
Locale locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;

SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a",locale);
SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a",Locale.US);

try {
    date = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(date));
} catch (Exception e) {
    //  Log.d("tttt","Ex prob ar >"+e.getMessage());
}
```